# How to wait for all threads to complete

Tags: java, multithreading

I created some workflow how to wait for all thread which I created. This example works in 99 % of cases but sometimes method waitForAllDone is finished sooner then all thread are completed. I know it because after waitForAllDone I am closing stream which is using created thread so then occurs exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

my thread start with:

```
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      process();
    } finally {
      Factory.close(this);
    }
  }
```

closing:

```
  protected static void close(final Client client) {
    clientCount--;
  }
```

when I creating thread I call this:

```
  public RobWSClient getClient() {
    clientCount++;
    return new Client();
  }
```

and clientCount variable inside factory:

```
  private static volatile int clientCount = 0;
```

wait:

```
  public void waitForAllDone() {
    try {
      while (clientCount > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      LOG.error("Error", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check out the doc of Semaphores in java. The example is nearly the same, what you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to protect the modification and reading of `clientCount` via `synchronized`. The main issue is that `clientCount--` and `clientCount++` are NOT an atomic operation and therefore two threads could execute `clientCount--` / `clientCount++` and end up with the wrong result.

Simply using `volatile` as you do above would ONLY work if ALL operations on the field were atomic. Since they are not, you need to use some locking mechanism. As Anton states, `AtomicInteger` is an excellent choice here. Note that it should be either `final` or `volatile` to ensure it is not thread-local.

That being said, the general rule post Java 1.5 is to use a `ExecutorService` instead of `Threads`. Using this in conjuction with Guava's `Futures` class could make waiting for all to complete to be as simple as:

```
Future<List<?>> future = Futures.successfulAsList(myFutureList);
future.get();
// all processes are complete
```

[Futures.successfulAsList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

Comment: but I have just one thread which is creating other threads. So who else can inc this value ?

Comment: You can increment the value from any number of threads you want, so long as you put the appropriate protections in place.

Comment: It is challenging to write unit tests to test threading. Usually you write a test and they cause it to repeat a large number of times. You can also add a library which will cause random thread context switching to help aid the discovery of thread bugs. See the concurrency section of `Clean Code` for a discussion of this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that the rest of your your code has no issues, but you can't increment volatile variable like this - `clientCount++`; Use `AtomicInteger` instead

Comment: why I cant increment it. Can you post some documentation ?

Comment: Cause it not atomic operation. During A = A + 1 value of A could have changed by another thread

Comment: @hudi consider ordering http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601 from amazon - it's nearly impossible to write a thread-safe code with the trial and error approach

Comment: but I have just one thread which is creating other threads. So who else can inc this value ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to wait for threads to terminate, is to use one of the high-level concurrency facilities. 
In this case, the easiest way would be to use an ExecutorService.

You would 'offer' a new task to the executor in this way:

```
...
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
...

Client client = getClient(); //assuming Client implements runnable
executor.submit(client);
...

public void waitForAllDone() {
    executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECOND) ; wait termination of all threads for 30 secs
... 
}
```

In this way, you don't waste valuable CPU cycles in busy waits or sleep/awake cycles.
See [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) docs for details.