# Java Waiting for all threads to complete

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future, futuretask

Edit: My question is different, it has no relevance to the linked question.

I've following code with completion handler.

```
FutureTask<Void> futureTask = new FutureTask<Void>(() -> {
    System.out.println("callback");
    return null;
});

Runnable task = () -> {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
    }
    futureTask.run();
};

new Thread(task).start();
new Thread(task).start();
```

Basically I'm looking for completion handler for variable number of tasks, or is there another approach?

I'm inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473070/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-complete) but seems it's part of some library while I'm looking for a native solution.

[Completable Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)???

Here's my attempt with completable futures with the result handler at the end.

```
public void test() {
    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> method1())
            .supplyAsync(() -> method2())
            .supplyAsync(() -> result());
}

public String method1() {
    System.out.println("calling 1");
    return "method1";
}

public String method2() {
    System.out.println("calling 2");
    return "method2";
}

public String result() {
    System.out.println("result");
    return "result";
}
```

Comment: Why can't `futureTask.run();` be replaced with in old method?

Comment: You could basically chain your tasks by implementing one that invokes `Thread.join()` on its predecessor(s) and then does whatever you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wait until all threads finish their work in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java)

Comment: @Ravindrababu not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your method `result()` returns a value that you want to retrieve, i.e. is declared like `Type result()`, you can use

```
CompletableFuture<Type> f = CompletableFuture.allOf(
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method1()),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method2())
).thenApply(_void -> result());
```

Each `runAsync` creates an individual asynchronous `CompletableFuture` that will be completed once the `Runnable` has been executed. It’s the same as `supplyAsync`, except that it doesn’t return a result.

`allOf` create a `CompletableFuture` that will be completed, once all specified futures are completed, hence, any chained dependent action will only run after all futures have been completed. By using `thenApply` we create a dependent future that will be completed with the return value of `result()`.

If `result()` is not intended to return a value, but just an action that should run after all other actions have been completed, you can use

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method1()),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method2())
).thenRun(() -> result());
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

One easy approach is to submit your Runnable(s) to an ExecutorService, then call [shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--), then call [awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
executor.submit(task);
executor.submit(task);

executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

No need to use CompletableFuture.

Comment: can you please make it a different caller and different responder, the executioner will be a different method and callback with result will be in a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Save the links to the threads you've created, and call `join()`

```
Thread a = new Thread(task);
Thread b = new Thread(task);
a.start();
b.start();

a.join();
b.join();
//guaranteed that both threads have completed here
```

Comment: It's going to block just there, I want to call these threads and forget about it, method returns, and I expect followup in the callback. thanks for teaching me `join` though

Comment: @user2727195 Better then to use another thread then to run the joins and the subsequent callback

Comment: ok, you've a point. just to expand knowledge here, do you know CompletableFuture and does it apply to my question?

Comment: @user2727195 But there's really no `Future` here... You're not looking for a result, just wanting to wait to start the next step after both threads have completed. So no, it does not apply here... Put another way "YOU HAVE NO FUTURE KID!" yuk yuk yuk yuk yuk... Okay, I've had my moment

Comment: lol no worries, but I'm open to other approaches, I'm not tied to this code in my question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much control you want you could use a ThreadPoolExecutor:

tpe.execute(Runnable);

Wait for the active count == 0;

then shutdown the executor.

Or keep the threads in a structure.

Wait for an specific TTL then interrupt them if the state is RUNNABLE

Comment: right. It seems like isTerminated() might be the method to wait for with this. I was going to add this to my answer, but thought it would overly complicate things

Comment: It just depends on how one wants to deal with them. I tend to avoid pools because I rather keep the capacity of pulling the plug when I want to

Comment: If you have a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, just use `invokeAll` to submit a list of tasks and wait for their completion. No need to use kludges like active count or shutdown.

Comment: If you have a list but if you don't, like building the runnables on the fly, this is what you do. No kludges. But if one of the runnables never gives up control your idea is stuck. that's why I use pools sparsely. Or have a TTL with an active count